# Does Windows GUI Vim perform font substitution for glyphs unavailable in current font?

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, font

MacVim's documentation specifically ([if obliquely](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/blob/54928cd17323e2851f28e41eb7b82da6322d65f8/runtime/doc/gui_mac.txt#L243)) mentions [font substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_substitution), and [I've found evidence online](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1438#issuecomment-277143647) that GTK2 gVim does it too.

But does Windows gvim?

N.B. I'm already aware of the `'guifontwide'` setting.